# What is the need for the static front page

Tags: theme-development, frontpage

I've recently asked a question about front-page.php and home.php usage ([How to setup front-page.php and home.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/294564/how-to-setup-front-page-php-and-home-php/)) and thought it will clear things out, but instead I realized(while testing/playing with the code) that I don't necessarily need to declare "Site Front Page" in "Settings → Reading", instead I tried to use the simple as it gets theme, by declaring style.css with the "Theme Name" and setting blank Index, header and footer php files.

So now I am really confused, as I don't see why would I need to declare front-page if I can manage this through index.php and set static content inside of it.

I'm probably missing here something very important and I would appreciate it if someone would explain this in simple language

Answer (score 1):

It mostly boils down to configurability for themes. While you are comfortable editing template files not everyone is. So looking at the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview) you can see the following:

When there is a `front-page.php` template it kind of ignores any setting in "Settings → Reading". (It still loads different content, but the template is forced)

But if you want to leave the choice of how the front page should behave/look to the user you can instead have a `home.php` which is only used if the user chooses to display posts on the front page. If he chooses to display a page this is respected as well.

I think if you look at the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview) things will clear up.